# CURL request with ~/.netrc file doesn't work

Tags: curl

I am trying to delete some of my post from http://ix.io

I have a file `test.txt` and `~/.netrc` with this content:

```bash
$ cat test.txt
Hello World!
$ cat ~/.netrc
machine my_ip_addr login my_username password my_passwd
```

I post it with:

```bash
$ curl --netrc -F 'f:1=@./test.txt' ix.io
http://ix.io/3LCu
# This link actually works
```

Now lets delete the post with this:

```bash
$ curl -n -X DELETE ix.io/3LCu
user required
# This does not work.
```

And the link still works! I want to delete it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The example of a `~/.netrc` file found in the `curl(1)` manual uses three separate lines (one for machine, one for login, and one for password). Following that pattern, does it make it work? Also, is `my_id_addr` in that file actually `ix.io` (it should be the address of the server you are connecting to).

Comment: Nope, still didn't work :(

Comment: see if it works when specifying the path using --netrc-file /home/user/.netrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just know that my_username should be replaced by my linux login username, and my_password should be replaced by my linux login password. Previously I make some different username and password.
So here's the content of the file:

```bash
$ cat ~/.netrc 
machine ix.io
login my_linux_login_name
password my_linux_login_password
```

And now, the CURL deletion request worked.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

EDIT: Now I think that it has to do with a comment, so previously the password format is something like `password #passwd`, maybe the `#passwd` is considered a comment because of the pound sign, so I get some error message like this:

```bash
$ curl -n [request]
cant add user username: no token
```

After changing the password so it doesn't contain pound sign, now the curl request worked. My bad :/